# The level keeps appearing as undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying out a code and it keeps returning as "level not defined under the singerprofile function,currently I have no idea what the problem is.Does anyone know?

```
function Singer(name,specialty,power,hitpoints,level,gender,rarity){ 

       this.name=name;   
        this.specialty=specialty;     
        this.power=power;     
        this.hitpoints=hitpoints;     
        this.level=level;     
        this.gender=gender;     
        this.rarity=rarity     


}  

var momobae=new Singer("momobae","k-pop",49,28,7,"female","Rare")
 var minibae=new Singer("minibae","k-pop",30,20,5,"male","common") 
 var array=[momobae,minibae] 

this.singerProfile=function(){ 
    console.log(name+" Level"+ level+" gender"+ gender+" power"+power+"!"+" Hitpoints:") 
} 
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){this.singerProfile(array[i]) 
};
```

Comment: Try `this.level`.

Comment: same for `gender` & `power`

Comment: oh its displaying it on console log now, but the values shown are undefined tho

Answer (score 1):

you have to fix your `singerProfile` and pass the current element as argument

```js
function Singer(name,specialty,power,hitpoints,level,gender,rarity){ 
  this.name=name;   
  this.specialty=specialty;     
  this.power=power;     
  this.hitpoints=hitpoints;     
  this.level=level;     
  this.gender=gender;     
  this.rarity=rarity     
}  

var momobae=new Singer("momobae","k-pop",49,28,7,"female","Rare")
var minibae=new Singer("minibae","k-pop",30,20,5,"male","common") 
var array=[momobae,minibae] 

this.singerProfile=function(elem){ 
  console.log(elem.name+" Level"+ elem.level+" gender"+ elem.gender+" power"+elem.power+"!"+" Hitpoints:") 
} 
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  this.singerProfile(array[i]) 
};
```